# Least common ancestor of multiple nodes in DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, least-common-ancestor

How can I find a least common ancestors of **multiple nodes** in a directed acyclic graph?

I've found quite a few papers on the topic but they all seem to find LCAs in DAG for **two** nodes.

Are there good algorithms for multiple nodes?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use the algorithm for two nodes recursively?

Comment: To clarify what @DennisMeng means: `lca(A, B, C) == lca(A, lca(B, C))`. Also note that `lca(A, B, C, D) == lca(lca(A, B), lca(C, D))`, so take your list of `n` nodes, build a binary tree on top of it that is as balanced as possible, and you only have to apply the binary `lca` `Θ(log n)` times.

Comment: dup? [LCA in DAG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865081/algorithm-to-find-lowest-common-ancestor-in-directed-acyclic-graph)

Comment: @vzn At a glance, it looks like the question you linked asks about LCA for two nodes, but OP here is explicitly looking for the case where there's 3 or more.

Comment: as the answer below & rhymoids comments indicate, apparently finding LCAs of multiple nodes is usually done recursively & iterating over pairwise LCAs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can modify the algorithm which is used for trees in a way that adopts to DAGs as well.

As you may know,there is an algorithm for finding LCA in trees with pre-process of *O(nlgn)* and process of *O(1)* for each query,so finding LCA of *k* nodes needs *O(k)* . More details about this algorithm can be found [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Range_Minimum_Query_%28RMQ%29).

Answer (score 1):

As @DennisMeng, @vzn and @user824425 already pointed out in the comments, under certain circumstances (!) the LCA of more than two nodes can be computed by **pairwise recursive application of the (binary) LCA operator**, e.g.:

```
lca(A, B, C, D) = lca(A, lca(B, lca(C, D)))
```

In functional programming, this is basically equivalent to a *reduce* (or [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))) operation.

However, this is only true for DAGs that are [Multitrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree) (or, alternatively, diamond-free [posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)). For general DAGs that don't have the multitree/diamond-free poset property, this approach will unfortunately *not work*.

Consider the following DAG representing a class hierarchy that features multiple inheritance (all edges are directed from the bottom to the top; the `X` indicates a crossing of two directed edges):

```
        Any
       /   \
  Boolean Value 
      |  X  |  \
    False True Unknown
```

Notably, the `True` and `False` nodes both have two direct ancestors, `Boolean` and `Value`. The first problem here is that this requires an LCA operator that can return more than one node, such as [JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/)'s [`getLCASet`](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/interfaces/LowestCommonAncestorAlgorithm.html#getLCASet(V,V)). Now, let's say we wanted to compute the LCA of {`False`, `True`, `Unknown`}: by simply looking at the graph, it is pretty obvious that `Value` is a direct ancestor of all three nodes. Direct pairwise reduction is no longer applicable, because the binary `getLCASet` operator can return more than one node, but conceivably one could use a stack-like approach where the computed ancestors get pushed back to the list of nodes. However, this does not produce the correct result, e.g.:

```
  True, False, Unknown
     \   /
     (LCA)
     /   \
Boolean, Value, Unknown
     \   /
     (LCA)
       |
      Any, Unknown
        \   /
        (LCA)
          |
         Any
```