# Check whether 2 nodes have any common parent(s) in a DAG graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

**The input is:**

An `int[][]`, each sub array contains 2 int as {parent, child}, means there is a path from `parent` -> `child`.

e.g

```
{ { 1, 3 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 6 }, { 5, 6 }, { 5, 7 }, { 4, 5 }, { 4, 8 }, { 8, 9 } };
```

Or as a tree structure:

```
  1   2   4
   \ /   / \
    3   5   8
     \ / \   \
      6   7   9
```

**The task is:**

Ｇiving 2 value (x, y), return a boolean value, to indicate whether they have any common parent(s).

Sample input and output:

```
[3, 8] => false
[5, 8] => true
[6, 8] => true
```

**My idea:**

- Represent the input data as a DAG graph, in which data are stored in a Map like this `Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>`, where key is the vertex, value is its adjacency list. And the direction in graph is reversed *(compared to input data)* as `child -> parent`, so that easy to search for parent.
- Use a function `findAvailableParents(Integer vertex)` to find all parents (direct and indirect) for a single vertex, and return `Set<Integer>`.
- Thus, only need to call `findAvailableParents()` once for each input vertex, then compare whether the 2 returned `Set`s have any intersection. Ｉf yes, then they have common parent; otherwise, they don't.

**My questions are:**

- The time complexity in the solution above is between O(1) ~ O(E), right? *(E is edge counts in the graph)*
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

A modified BFS might help you to solve the problem

**Algorithm: checkCommonParent**

```
def checkCommonParent(G, v1, v2):

# Create a queues for levelorder traversal
q1 = []

# Mark all the vertices as not visited
# This will be used to cover all the parts of graph
visited = [False]*(len(G.Vertices))


for v in G.Vertices:
    if visited[v] == False:
        q1.append(v)
        visited[v] = True

    # Check a connected component and see if it has both vertices exists.
    # If it exists, that means they have a common ancestor
    v1Visited = False
    v2Visited = False
    while ((len(q1) > 0) or (len(q2) > 0)):
      while len(q1) > 0:
        curVertex = q1.popleft()
        for adjV in curVertex.adjecentVertices:
        if visited[adjV] == False:
            q1.append(adjV)
            visited[adjV] = True

            if adjV == v1:
              v1Visited = True
            elif adjV == v2:
              v2Visited = True


    if v1Visited and v2Visited: 
            return True


return False
```

I guess the idea is clear on the modification of BFS. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have multiple inputs, now BFS would take around O(E) time to process each input.

All inputs can be queried in **O(logn)** if we do some pre computation  which should take about **O(nlogn)** time

basically you want to find what is the **Least common ancestor** of those nodes 
this thread in [topcoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/) discusses the logic for a tree which can be extended to a **DAG** 
You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865081/algorithm-to-find-lowest-common-ancestor-in-directed-acyclic-graph) question for some further ideas

If an LCA exists between 2 nodes, then they have a common parent

Comment: The issue is, from the graph in question, you can see not all nodes starts from a single root node, so it's not a typical binary tree.

Comment: LCA can be found in a DAG, check out the discussion in the stack overflow thread in the answer